# Debian Wheezy installation with preseed

Tags: linux, debian, system-installation

I have a USB stick with netinst version of Debian Wheezy (testing). I am trying to load a preseed file, named "preseed.cfg" in the USB root folder (same folder as initrd.gz). I use GRUB and my entry looks like this:

```
menuentry 'Debian Wheezy automatic install' {
  linux /vmlinuz preseed/file=/hd-media/preseed.cfg auto=true priority=critical
  initrd /initrd.gz
}
```

Now everytime the installer starts it says `cannot find file:///hd-media/preseed.cfg. Will continue with manual install"`. Do I have the wrong syntax? Also, I thought any file named "preseed.cfg" will be detected automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the line I used for `grub1` when I was doing this on Lenny using CDs.

```
append vga=normal initrd=/install.amd/initrd.gz preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed.txt debian-installer/locale=en_US console-keymaps-at/keymap=us --
```

Other than the fact that you're using `grub2`, it doesn't look significantly different.

You need to make sure that the path you're trying to use is actually the correct path. Does the USB installer mount itself to `/hd-media`? I haven't tried this with Wheezy (yet) but that doesn't feel right to me.

To check, start up the installer then switch to the shell console (I believe it's 4, so press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>) then look around the system for your `pressed.cfg` file.

The file path that you list must match the exact file path of the `preseed.cfg` from the root of the booted installer.

Comment: Silly me, it was true that the usb was never mounted, because I dowloaded the netinst version instead of the hd-media version. Currently there is a bug in WHeezy install that makes the hd-media version hang when scanning for the ISO file under some circumstances, so I changed to netinst without thinking what implications it would get to the mounting process.

Answer (score 1):

Could you add `rootdelay=60` to your boot parameter, to see if it works?
Sometimes the kernel needs time to have USB devices detected, ready, drivers loaded and filesystems mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and apparently the contents of the installation image (Debian Wheezy 7.3) was mounted under /cdrom/ instead of /hd-media/ - however, I did use unetbootin to create the USB-disk, which might affect the location of the mount.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all on this thread...

For debian-8.4.0-i386-CD-1.iso (32bits), installing on an old Toshiba Dynabook Satellite J40 (Pentium M 2GHz, single core) FROM the CDROM (700MB) disk and using the preseed file on an USB KEY, I succeed first, by following the advice to gain the terminal (BusyBox) using Ctrl + Alt + F2, with the "rootdelay=90"...

The USB KEY was mounted at "/media", so my config file was at "/media/file.cfg"...

The "/hd-media/file.cfg" DID NOT WORK FOR this particular notebook...

Then, the working option (for my case) is:

```
rootdelay=90 preseed/file=/media/file.cfg
```

I am not sure if it is the same for ANY PC or just this particular one...

*Also, the USB KEY is a "pre-historic" 256MB PQI with FAT16 format...